# asp.Net prevent server side link with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an ImageButton as follows

```
<asp:ImageButton OnClientClick="javascript:merge();" ID="MenuLinkMerge" Text="Merge" ToolTip="Merge" SkinID="Merge32" runat="server" onclick="MenuLinkMerge_Click" />
```

merge() will call

```
function merge() {
    if (IDList.length > 0) {
        alert("go");
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("No companies were selected.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

but whether I return true or false the MenuLinkMerge_Click is always called server side and the page is redirected. I only want the page to change if IDList.length > 0 otherwise display the alert and do nothing.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your onclientclick handler to this -> OnClientClick="return merge();"

Comment: Thank you very much, simple answers are the ones I like ;)